# When do travelling (accelerating) charged particles emit radiation in their direction of travel and when perpendicular to their velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, radiation

I have read numerous things saying that a travelling charged particle emits radiation primarily in a cone in the direction of travel, and other places say the radiation is emitted and polarized in an azimuthal direction (or normal, or perpendicular, or transverse, etc.)

I am confused....